# Python moto fails to match valid Eventbridge pattern

Tags: aws-event-bridge, moto

I have a couple of Eventbridge events (`{"root": "child"}` and `{"root": ["child"]}`) which I want to match against pattern `{"root": ["child"]}`.

Both these matches are valid according to `aws events test-event-pattern` -

```
aws events test-event-pattern --event '{"id": 1234567890, "source": "my-source", "detail-type": "my-detail-type", "detail": {"root": "child"}, "account": 1234567890, "region": "eu-west-1", "time": "1970-12-20T20:00:00Z"}' --event-pattern '{"source": ["my-source"], "detail": {"root": ["child"]}}' --output text
True
```

```
aws events test-event-pattern --event '{"id": 1234567890, "source": "my-source", "detail-type": "my-detail-type", "detail": {"root": ["child"]}, "account": 1234567890, "region": "eu-west-1", "time": "1970-12-20T20:00:00Z"}' --event-pattern '{"source": ["my-source"], "detail": {"root": ["child"]}}' --output text
True
```

But I can only get the former pattern to match when I use `moto` to mock the message flow (script at bottom)

```
 % python scripts/demo/moto_events/test_moto.py
{"root": "child"} -> True
{"root": ["child"]} -> False
```

Have I made a mistake here or is `moto` events behaviour diverging from AWS Eventbridge ?

TIA

cc @BertBlommers

ps using `moto` `2.0.11`

---

```py
from moto import mock_events, mock_sqs

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

import boto3, copy, json, yaml

EventBase=yaml.safe_load("""
Source: my-source
DetailType: my-detail-type
""")

Statement=yaml.safe_load("""
Effect: Allow
Principal:
  Service: events.amazonaws.com
Action: "sqs:SendMessage"
Resource: "*"
""")

def drain_sqs(sqs, queueurl, nmax=100):
    messages, count = [], 0
    while True:
        resp=sqs.receive_message(QueueUrl=queueurl)
        if ("Messages" not in resp or
            count > nmax):
            break
        messages+=resp["Messages"]
        count+=1
    return messages

@mock_events
@mock_sqs
def test_event_pattern(detail,
                       eventbase=EventBase,
                       statement=Statement):
    events, sqs, = boto3.client("events"), boto3.client("sqs")
    policy=json.dumps({"Version": "2012-10-17",
                       "Statement": [statement]})
    queue=sqs.create_queue(QueueName="my-queue",
                           Attributes={"Policy": policy})
    queueurl=queue["QueueUrl"]
    queueattrs=sqs.get_queue_attributes(QueueUrl=queueurl)["Attributes"]
    queuearn=queueattrs["QueueArn"]
    pattern={"detail": detail["pattern"]}
    events.put_rule(Name="my-rule",
                    State="ENABLED",
                    EventPattern=json.dumps(pattern))
    events.put_targets(Rule="my-rule",
                       Targets=[{"Id": "my-target-id",
                                 "Arn": queuearn}])
    event=copy.deepcopy(eventbase)
    event["Detail"]=json.dumps(detail["event"])
    events.put_events(Entries=[event])
    return drain_sqs(sqs, queue["QueueUrl"])

if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        for detail in [{"event": {"root": "child"},
                        "pattern": {"root": ["child"]}},
                       {"event": {"root": ["child"]},
                        "pattern": {"root": ["child"]}}]:
            messages=test_event_pattern(detail)
            print ("%s -> %s" % (json.dumps(detail["event"]),
                                 bool(len(messages))))
    except ClientError as error:
        print ("Error: %s" % str(error))
```

Comment: Looks like that use case is not yet supported in Moto. Can you open an issue on https://github.com/spulec/moto with these details?

Comment: I will do. Thank you.